# Vue Bootstrap Tabs - mounted works before beforeDestroy

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have an issue this Vue Bootstrap Tab. When I click on tab-2 then tab-1, the first mounted 'tabl-1', then 'tabl-2' destroyed.

If I click on tab-1, then tab-2, everything works as it must, 'tabl-1' component destroys, then 'tabl-2' mounted.

Does anybody knows why it is working this way and how to fix it?

```
tabs: [
  {key: 'tab-1', name: 'Tab 1', icon: 'fas fa-cogs', uniqueKey: this.$uuid.v4(), component: 'tabl-1'},
  {key: 'tab-2', name: 'Tab 2', icon: 'fas fa-cogs', uniqueKey: this.$uuid.v4(), component: 'tabl-2'}
]

<b-tabs v-model="tabIndex">
  <b-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.key" lazy>
    <template v-slot:title> <i class="mr-1" :class="tab.icon"></i> {{ tab.name }} </template>
    <p class="mb-0">
      <component :is="tab.component" :key="tab.uniqueKey" />
    </p>
  </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using lazy remove it.
lazy attribute mount the component when its tab is activated but once the tab is inactive it **unmounts** the component so when you come back to it you will see a brand new instance of it because it was unmounted.
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#lazy-loading-tab-content

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33448547)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).